# How to trigger a function with jest test case library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I tried to trigger a (react with typescript) method using jest test case but it is showing function is not covered.

Actual function in the component (react with typescript):

```js
const conditionHandler = (
  event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof props.filter.condition>
) => {
  const updatedFilter: FieldfilterInterface = {
    ...props.filter,
    condition: event.target.value,
  };

  props.onChange(updatedFilter, props.index);
};
```

Test case I tried:

```js
const mockProps = {
  filter: {
    fieldName: "Abcd",
    operator: '=',
    fieldValue: 'date',
    condition: 'OR',
    type: SearchFilterType.Text,
  } as FieldfilterInterface,
  showAddButton: true,
  options: ["option1", "option2"],
  showDeleteBtn: true,
  onChange: jest.fn(),
  onAddButtonClick: jest.fn(),
  onDeleteBtnClick: jest.fn(),
};

it("handles condition method", () => {
  render(<FilterComponent {...mockProps} index={1} />);

  const selectElement = screen.getByTestId('ConditionId');

  if (selectElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    fireEvent.change(
      selectElement,
      { target: { value: 'newCondition' } }
    );

    expect(mockProps.onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      {
        ...mockProps.filter,
        condition: 'newCondition',
      },
      1
    );
  }
});
```